# Android AIDL for local service

Tags: android, aidl, android-service-binding, android-binder

Can i able to use the AIDL interface to communicate with the localservice within same package in android? without penalty?

Comment: yes, drawback : it will go through RPC even if it could not

Comment: AIDL when used locally does NOT do any RPC @Selvin

Comment: If so,then it is possible to use AIDL interface to communicate with local service (in 'xyz' package) with my client component such as 'Acitivty' (in same 'xyz' package) without any additional overhead? @pskink

Comment: no need to change your code, no matter if it is remote call or local one